# Problem using [window insertSubview]

Tags: uiviewcontroller, subview

When I use the following code to insert a view on top of a split view, I am getting orientation problems.

Here is the code I use,

```
[window addSubview:aSplitViewController.view];
[window insertSubview:aViewController.view aboveSubview:aSplitViewController.view];
```

What happens here is that the view controller ( which contains labels and buttons) loads in landscape mode while its components load in portrait mode...

I feel that the `window insertSubview` is creating this problem because when I used `[window addSubview:aViewController.view]` the view is getting displayed properly in landscape mode with its components in landscape mode as well...

Here is the code which I feel is giving me the problem

In my App Delegate

```
- (void) makeSplitViewController {

    NSMutableArray *controllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tabBarController.viewControllers];

    // First tabbbar item
    // detail view
    detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navDetailView = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController] autorelease];
    navDetailView.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;


    // root view
    rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    rootViewController.detailViewController = detailViewController;
    rootViewController.navigationItem.title = @"List";

    UINavigationController *navRootView = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController] autorelease];
    navRootView.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    navRootView.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

    splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    splitViewController.tabBarItem.title = @"Face Sheet";
    splitViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gear1.png"];
    splitViewController.navigationItem.title = @"Face Sheet";
    splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navRootView, navDetailView, nil];
    splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
    splitViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [controllers addObject:splitViewController];

    // Second tabbbar item
    scoreViewController = [[ScoreCardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" bundle:nil];
    scoreViewController.tabBarItem.title = @"Score Card";
    scoreViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gear1.png"];
    scoreViewController.navigationItem.title = @"Score Card";
    [controllers addObject:scoreViewController];

    tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Create tabbar
    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    //tabBarController.delegate = self;

    // Set window
    [window addSubview:splashController.view];
    [window insertSubview:tabBarController.view belowSubview:splashController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    application.statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;

    return YES;
}
```

and here is the code in my SplashScreenView

```
- (IBAction) proceedButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    // Initialize loginpopview
    PhysicianLoginViewController *loginViewController = [[PhysicianLoginViewController alloc] init];

    popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:loginViewController];
    popOverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(350, 200);
    popOverController.delegate = self;

    // Set a notification to dismiss it later
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loginViewControllerDone:) name:@"loginViewControllerDone"  object:popOverController.contentViewController];

    // Present popover
    if ([popOverController isPopoverVisible])
    {
        [popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
    else 
    {

        [popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(485, 600, 100, 100) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
    }

}

// Dismiss popview controller and setup the tabbar
- (void)loginViewControllerDone:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

    // Button in content view controller was tapped, dismiss popover...
    [self.popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

    // remove subview
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];

    // set tabbar
    i3EAppDelegate *appDelegate = (i3EAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    [appDelegate makeSplitViewController];

}
```

It would be great if someone could point out where I am going wrong. I have been stuck with this problem for quite a few days and I have tried everything that comes to my mind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the rotation handling of UIWindow and UIViewController just isn't designed to work that way. Quoth [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW40):

> In an iOS application, the window object does much of the work associated with changing the current orientation. However, it works in conjunction with the application’s view controllers to determine whether an orientation change should occur at all, and if so, what additional methods should be called to respond to the change. Specifically, it works with the view controller whose root view was most recently added to, or presented in, the window. In other words, the window object works only with the frontmost view controller whose view was displayed using one of the mechanisms described in “Presenting a View Controller’s View.”

This paragraph is somewhat vague and contradictory (is it the most recently added view controller, or the controller for the topmost view?), and in practice doesn't seem to necessarily match observations. The bottom line is that adding multiple views to a UIWindow will screw up the automatic rotation handling.

You should change your code to use `presentModalViewController:animated:` (maybe with `modalPresentationStyle` set to `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`) or a UIPopoverController instead of adding multiple subviews to the window.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. I have had a problem using presentModalViewController... here is the link which shows what my problem is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624457/problem-using-presentmodalviewcontroller-in-ipad.. could you have a look at it and help if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[aViewController.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```