# Problem using presentModalViewController in Ipad

Tags: modalviewcontroller, ipad

In my current Ipad app, I have a split screen view in which the detail view is a scroll view containing 4 table views. The functionality I was trying to achive was that when I click any row of the table in the scroll view, a screen is show containing additional information and I used presentModalViewController to try to get this functionality.

say for example, I have 3 files aViewController, bViewController, cViewController.. I am writing the code for splitViewController in the appDelegate file of my project and I keep the 3 view Controllers (aViewController, bViewController, cViewController) as subviews of the 
splitViewController...

Now in one of my ViewControllers, say **aViewController**, in its **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**, I add the code as follows

This is what I did,

```
PopOverControllerContents *popContents = 
        [[PopOverControllerContents alloc] 
         initWithNibName:@"PopOverControllerContents" 
         bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 popContents.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:popContents animated:YES
```

An important thing I want to mention is that, my app's default orientation is landscape mode and hence I changed the orientation of PopOverControllerContents to landscape orientation.

When I build and run and when I click any row in **aViewController**, a popup view does come but its totally out of position and its bottom part gets cut off.

Would anyone be able to tell me what I am doing wrong and How I can correct it?

Comment: When you say "its totally out of position and its bottom part gets cut off", are you referring to the form sheet itself or to your content inside the form sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[UIViewController presentModalViewController::]` supposes that your view controller is the root controller or it is somewhere in the controller hierarchy. When you say that your controller views are subview of a `SplitViewController` are they also its child controllers? You should try to present the modal controller from the `SplitViewController` or check that you controllers are it's child controllers (new feature in iOS 5).